# R Confussion Matrix - Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

Although there are other reports for the same error message none is helping in my case.

I have prepared my own data, splitted as below but it is impossible to obtain the confussion matrix.

```
test_index <- createDataPartition(y = workingData$PM10, times = 1, p = 0.5, list = FALSE)
train_set <- workingData[-test_index,]
test_set <- workingData[test_index,]

train_knn <- train(PM10 ~. , method= "knn" , data = train_set)

y_hatknn <- predict(train_knn, train_set, type = "raw")

confusionMatrix(y_hatknn, test_set$PM10)
```

The last line above gives

```
Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.
```

I would like to upload the data for reproduction, but can provide the basic:

```
str(workingData)
'data.frame':   3653 obs. of  3 variables:
' $ Date   : num  2e+07 2e+07 2e+07 2e+07 2e+07 ...
' $ Rain_mm: num  0.1 6.7 0 1.4 0.8 1.8 15.3 0 2.6 3.8 ...
' $ PM10   : num  -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 ...
```

PM10 being pollution PM10 levels.

How to resolve it?

Adding more info:

After the original error:

> confusionMatrix(y_hatknn, test_set$PM10)
> Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.

I try to set as factor...

> confusionMatrix(y_hatknn, as.factor(test_set$PM10))
> Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.

With the prediction as factor...

> confusionMatrix(as.factor(y_hatknn), test_set$PM10)
> Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.

With both parameters as factors...

> confusionMatrix(as.factor(y_hatknn), as.factor(test_set$PM10))
> Error in confusionMatrix.default(as.factor(y_hatknn), as.factor(test_set$PM10)) :
> the data cannot have more levels than the reference

Really need to get is sorted out

Comment: Pd: where can I upload the data for you to try it?

Comment: Please make your question minimal and reproducible by providing small example data with code. Visit [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: To share data, you can use the `dput()` function. So run `dput(workingData)` and copy the result into a codeblock in your question. However, given the size of workingData, this may not work. If it is too large to share, you can also make a 'toy' dataset to share that is smaller but replicates your issue. Also, [do not solicit answers via off-site channels](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425033/how-can-i-handle-off-site-contact-links-in-the-question), it is not permitted on SO.